# How to inspect react state without react devtools

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs

I need to debug a React application on IE11 (on Browserstak) and I'd like to access components state from the console.
Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Right-click > Inspect Element > Console Then just print your state to the console on the appropriate moments, and use a debugger to pause execution.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I need. I don't wanna print out stuff in console because I'm debugging my production environment.

Comment: @s.susini You could check `window.<some random variable>`, then enable debugging if that’s `true`.

Comment: I have the same type of issue, working behind a coroporate firwall and with older versions of browsers. I am unable to use the redux dev tools extension. If only there would be a standalone version similar to POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs [Using Global Variables](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-global-variables)

> reading the global variable explicitly from the window object

```
const $ = window.$;
```

Somewhere in your code, you should assign your component state to a window variable and then access it from your console by console logging the window variable.